# Login to Azure ML workspace from Azure Databricks notebook

Tags: python-3.x, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-databricks

I am writing a python notebook in Azure Databricks cluster to perform an Azure Machine learning experiment. I have created an Azure ML workspace and instantiating a workspace object in my notebook as follows:

```
id = InteractiveLoginAuthentication(force=False, tenant_id=AzureTenantId)
ws = Workspace(SubscriptionId, ResourceGroupName, WorkspaceName, auth = id)
```

I am trying to perform an interactive login to azure to access the workspace but when I run the notebook I get the following error. the notebook is written in python

```
Falling back to use azure cli credentials. This fall back to use azure cli credentials will be removed in the next release. 
Make sure your code doesn't require 'az login' to have happened before using azureml-sdk, except the case when you are specifying AzureCliAuthentication in azureml-sdk.
Performing interactive authentication. Please follow the instructions on the terminal.
From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x7f4736825d08>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509)
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'
```

Could someone help me resolve this issue? Is it really an OpenSSL issue?

Answer (score 1):

are you following the Azure Doc over here?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-configure-environment#azure-databricks

Have you looked at these notebooks? - https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/tree/master/how-to-use-azureml/azure-databricks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pip install azureml-sdk[databricks]` to install the SDK on Azure Databricks cluster. The pip extra ensures that certain dependencies are pinned to correct versions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install azureml-sdk[databricks] library on your cluster. Not azureml-sdk, but azureml-sdk[databricks] : http://prntscr.com/mpk05g